# Is it possible to declare and initialize a texture inside a .metal file?

Tags: textures, metal

I was just wondering, instead of creating a texture, initializing data to it via blit command encoder if it is private or by using `MTLTexture replace` if it not private, and passing it to GPU using `setFragmentTexture`, can I have the texture already ready to use inside the `.metal` file similar to:

```
constant const texture2d<half> my_texture = {/* Texture Data */};
```

Is this possible?

Comment: It is not possible to do that.

Comment: @JustSomeGuy Do you have a citation or more details? It would be nice to have this question answered before getting Roomba deleted.

Comment: My citation is that this is not mentioned anywhere in the spec and that's just not how API works: each resource has to have a CPU `MTLResource` object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74755212/is-it-possible-to-declare-and-initialize-a-texture-inside-a-metal-file?noredirect=1#comment131934574_74755212):

> It is not possible to do that. Each resource has to have a CPU `MTLResource` object.